# Serve pdf file with Falcon RES API

Tags: python, rest, httpresponse, falconframework

I'm trying to serve a pdf file using Falcon REST API, but I can't find any example of it.

So far this is what I've tried:

```
class ReportResource:

  def on_get(self, req, resp):
    filename="./evaluation.pdf"
    resp.downloadable_as = filename
    resp.content_type = 'report/pdf'
    resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

What I get is an empty pdf file that, of course, I can't open. I'm guessing I'm not loading the file content in the response, but I'm not an expert in python and I have no idea how I should do it.

If I try this:

```
resp.stream, resp.stream_len = open(filename)
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 130: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm totally sure the file is there.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, done. I needed to open the file in binary mode. I leave it here in case anyone needs the example sinsce I coulnd't find anyone myself.

```
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    filename="./evaluation.pdf"
    resp.downloadable_as = filename
    resp.content_type = 'application/pdf'

    resp.stream= open(filename, 'rb')
    resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```